# command in docker run and inside docker not behaving similarly

Tags: bash, docker

I have script that load a database into RAM and print the adress of the first data into a file (`db_REGISTER`), and I want to run it inside a docker. This script works fine when it is launched inside a bash after launching the docker with `-it`

```
$ docker run -it --env-file $FILE -v $wkp:/app dev_machine
$$ /app/scripts/loadBase.sh
```

db_REGISTER

```
<some random number>
```

However when I launch the same script with docker run directly, the script works but the adress printed is always 0, and I cannot use the database afterward.

```
$ docker run -it --env-file $FILE -v $wkp:/app dev_machine /app/scripts/loadBase.sh
```

db_REGISTER

```
0
```

Does that mean that the second command does not have access to a persistant adress in the RAM ? What should I do to correct that ?

EDIT : After some advice, I tried to tweak the `--ipc` setting. Using `--ipc="host"` made it work. I guess this was a problem of shared RAM

Answer (score 0):

You could try to mount your file inside the Docker container before executing the command:

`docker run -it --env-file $FILE -v $PWD/scripts:/t -w /t  dev_machine loadBase.sh`

Comment: The script and db_REGISTER are already inside a volume. I did not put it in the question because I did not think it mattered for my problem